# How to access vagrant from browser in localhost?

Tags: localhost, vagrant

In vagrant, set hostname as `test.my.domain`. Installed an application in it. Want to access it from browser as `http://test.my.domain`. Except set `/etc/hosts`, is there any tools for mapping it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to make an entry in your `/etc/hosts` file then you will need to manage DNS on a server. But really, I implore you to manage your DNS client side with `/etc/hosts`. Right now you're likely configured by default to use your Router as your DNS Server. See if you can [log into your Router](https://192-168-1-1ip.mobi/) and add a DNS [A Record](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/dns-records/dns-a-record/) for the IP Address of your Vagrant VM. If your router doesn't support the mapping of DNS records, then you will need to stand up a BIND, PowerDNS, Active Directory, etcd server to provide DNS for your network. Then you can [reconfigure](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-change-dns-servers-on-most-popular-routers-2617995) your router to hand out this server to your clients over DHCP so they automatically use it.

However, I have to warn you that since Vagrant is an automation framework meant for [type-2 hypervisors](https://searchservervirtualization.techtarget.com/definition/hosted-hypervisor-Type-2-hypervisor), the VMs are not typically meant to be used in a production environment. Or one resembling one that has traffic routed to it by DNS. In this situation you should be using a [type-1 hypervisor](https://www.proxmox.com/en/) or [container host](http://kubernetes.io/) to run your applications and expose them with [load balancers](https://metallb.universe.tf/installation/) that you point your DNS entries to.

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer.